# Joyride Foundation Custom Override

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

The JS library that I am working with atm within my site is joyride and I would like to customize how it works with a certain part my site.

I have joyride applied to to a icon within my services page. This is the only place that I want joy ride to work. However I am experiencing an issue when I place joyride here at this certain location.

The issue..When my page loads the screen is automatically scrolled to a random location..I'm guessing it's trying to find where I called joyride?

This is not what I need to happen..obviously :)

What I would like to achieve is for joyride to only be activated when the user arrives directly at the services page (which contains the icons) and not on the page load which means eliminating the load scroll.

Is there away to achieve this? Or at least take away the random scrolling placement problem.

```
<ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
    <li data-id="repair" data-text="Close" data-options="tip_location: left; nub_position:left; prev_button: false">
        <p>Click or tap each icon to learn more about our services</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here's the link

http://kapena.github.io/pp_web/

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `scroll_speed` to `0` it should prevent the scroll effect.

```
$(document).foundation({
    offcanvas : {
        open_method: "move",
        close_on_click : true
    }
    joyride : {
         scroll_speed: 0;
    }
});

$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to disable joyride..Just want to stop it from scrolling to the random spot on my page..How would you how exactly do you use `Foundation.libs.joyride.off();`

Comment: Thax again! Tried that..However that just solution just stopped Joyride from appearing all together

Comment: @BrentWhite Are you sure? It works for me.  Might be you made a typo

Comment: I'll give it another go :)

Comment: It works but I now no longer can see the information that joyride wants to display..So no scroll seems to = no joyride..

Comment: This dude seems to be having the same issue as me..https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3267

Comment: @BrentWhite What happens if you make the `scroll_to` function do nothing ?  https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js#L463

Comment: How exactly would you make it do nothing?

Comment: @BrentWhite `Foundation.libs.joyride.scroll_to = function(){};` or replace it with the `scroll_to : function () {},` in `foundation.joyride.js` it will prevent scrolling. If it works, you can patch it with some kind of test so it will scroll only when you want it to scroll. Both this and scroll_speed: 0; solutions should work.